# Trying to replicate a view with no success

Tags: views, navigation

I'm currently working on my drupal site and I have trouble replicating one view. This is the view I'm talking about.

[image: View]

I have replicated the drop down menu, the search bar "with the exception of a placeholder" and the list of episodes as well, but I'm having trouble replicating something where it autoselects/autodefaults the dropdown menu item based on the show name. (represented by the red arrow) I have tried everything, contextual filters, remember options, but nothing works.

Can you help me, I'm at loss of words here as to how to replicate it? Your help would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you say, "autoselects/autodefaults the dropdown menu item based on the show name," what are you trying to do, exactly? What show name you are trying to auto-select? Is this view capable of showing shows with other show names? If so, and say you have ten shows in that list, which one do you want to be the default?

Are you trying to have links to that same view from different places in the site and you want a link on the Tech Guy page to automatically filter the Tech Guy shows, and a link on the Fictional Mister Podcast page to automatically filter to the Fictional Mister Podcast shows?

Comment: Well... Since the time that has passed, I installed Views Filter Harmonizer which solved one part of the autoselects/autodefaults. "At initial page load, auto-fill the exposed filter form with the contextual filter value(s) applied to the page." But now I'm trying to get the NID to display the Parent Node through Node Hierarchy in order to get the auto-fill working. I tried everyone of the contextual filters but to no avail; I'm guessing an option would be to try a PHP code but I don't know how to get a NID from the Parent Node. If anybody knows any calls or code, leave them here.